# connection to gitlab container registry refused

Tags: docker, containers, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I have enabled the Continer Registry on Gitlab under the gitlab.yml file where I have set the `registry_external_url` to look like this `http://registry.domain`. I have configured my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to log in Docker this way: `docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY` an I have set the following docker image:

```
image: docker:18-git

  services:

    - docker:18-dind
```

But whenever I run the pipeline, I get the following error:

> Error logging in to v2 endpoint, trying next endpoint: Get https://registry.domain/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry.domain on IP adress : no such host"

I'm thinking it's because I'm using http instead of https but I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Can you view the registry in your browser by opening its URL? `no such host` tells that the hostname doesn't exist.

Comment: No I cannot that's the problem. I have set the url to be http://registry.mydomain but whenever I run the job I get an error stating that the connection to https://registry.mydomain:443 is refused

Answer (score 1):

In your gitlab-runner running node's `/etc/hosts` file add (replace with your proper IP)

```
192.168.12.34 registry.domain
```

Then you may get `insecure registry` error

1. `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (gitlab-runner running node's)

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
}
```

2. Restart docker in the node

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

Comment: I did all of that but I still get the refuse to connect error. Although I do specify http, the registry still points to an https adress

Comment: Did you restart `docker` service?

Comment: yes I restarted the docker service. I don't know how to make the registry point to the http port.

Comment: Did you crated given `docker.json` file on host PC? I.e. not in gitlab docker!

Comment: @Lubo If you mean `daemon.json` file, YES, had to create it.